# Using a WPF DataGrid with Reactivui

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, reactiveui

I'm trying to bind a WPF DataGrid to a ReactiveList. Unfortunately the bind don't show any row.

I tried to use a normal List as Datasource as well.
I also tried the AutoGenerateColumn function and to use Binding to the properties(only getters, no setters) of AuswertungsEntry. 
But the properties never gotten accessed at runtime.

My view.xaml:

```
...

<DataGrid x:Name="AuswertungGrid" Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fehler" Binding="{Binding Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" 1. Auswertung" Binding="{Binding ok1}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" 1. Auswahl"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" 2. Auswertung"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" 2. Auswahlt"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header=" Gesamt"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

My binding in  view.xaml.cs:

```
this.WhenActivated((d) =>
{                
    this.OneWayBind(ViewModel,
         viewModel => viewModel.Entries,
         view => view.AuswertungGrid.ItemsSource)
         .DisposeWith(d);
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
...
 private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<ReactiveList<AuswertungsEntry>> _Entries;
 public ReactiveList<AuswertungsEntry> Entries => _Entries.Value;

 public AuswertungViewModel()
 {
    _Entries = this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Data)
                   .Where(x => x != null)
                   .SelectMany(x => CreateDataSource())
                   .ToProperty(this, x => x.Entries);
 }

 public async Task<ReactiveList<AuswertungsEntry>> CreateDataSource()
 {
    return await AuswertungsService.GetAuswertung();
 }
...
```

The Service is returning correct Data. I checked that already. But no rows are getting generated, not with the GenerateAutoColumn feature nor manually.

I would expect, that DataGrid would get filled with the supplied data.

Comment: Did you confirm that `CreateDataSource` gets called? Please provide a [minimal repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue.

Comment: We deprecated ReactiveList, it sometimes doesn't do great with these sorts of scenario. Consider using a ObservableCollection, or a SourceList from DynamicData.

Comment: It may, ReactiveList doesn't properly support the INotifyCollectionChanged event, where it can send all the values in the range in one event. Hence one of the reasons why it was deprecated since a lot of the ItemsControl don't support range values that well.

Comment: @GlennWatson Thanks for your support, I changed my DataSource to be a SourceList and it is working. If you like you can change your comment to an answert so i will mark it as solved.

Comment: @mm8 thanks for your input. After I changed my DataSource to be a SourceList it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReactiveList<T>` was deprecated a while back within the ReactiveUI project.

One of the issues is it doesn't produce INotifyCollectionChanged events in a way that WPF always expects, especially when you are adding ranged based values.

I would recommend you use a `SourceList<T>` if you need to mutate the data, or a `ObservableCollection<T>` otherwise.